# need to display image upon hover - image map using raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, raphael

I am trying to create an imagemap where the user can hover over a specific object and a photo will popup. I am using Raphaeljs to create my objects that will be hovered over and all the objects will be overlaid on top of a photo. I have completed this part, but now I am trying to make an image pop up when the user hovers over the object. I am very new to javascript so I appreciate any help that you can give.

Here is my code so far:

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Raphael Play</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/raphael.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/our_script.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    google.load("jquery", "1.6");
</script>

    <style type="text/css">         
        #canvas_container {  
            width: 718px;  
            border: 1px solid #aaa; 
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1000;

        }  

    </style>  
</head>  
<body>  


    <div id="canvas_container"></div>   


    <div id="imagePhoto">
        <img src="photo/photoMap.jpg" alt="map" />
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my actual javascript page:

```
window.onload = function() {
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 718, 454);
var building_left = paper.path("M102.262,272.369L86.617,170.243h-0.001l-1.628-10.632l-0.361-2.355l-0.772-5.045,c3.807-1.873,16.113-3.42,19.919-5.295c16.499-8.117,24.5-16.563,40.998-24.682l5.64,38.233l-44.377,6.801l15.644,102.126,L102.262,272.369L102.262,272.369z");
var building_right = paper.path("M 179.229,294.203 255.138,224.116 255.139,224.116 261.668,218.086 264.791,215.203 268.54,211.74 224.758,164.323 211.355,176.695 241.813,209.682 165.905,279.771 179.229,294.203 z");
var building_middle = paper.path("M 121.679,269.394 165.432,284.533 198.59,188.698 154.837,173.561 121.679,269.394 z");
var auditorium = paper.path("M 308.953,287.341 324.306,272.827 434.898,253.264 442.893,259.055 435.941,268.646 457.102,388.746 348.424,407.501 341.092,366.764 312.423,372.086 297.54,289.234 308.953,287.341 z");
var building_hall = paper.path("M 353.574,219.885 345.305,171.459 428.613,157.234 436.881,205.659 353.574,219.885 z");
var office = paper.path("M 476.971,200.559 436.881,172.165 487.543,100.641 527.631,129.036 476.971,200.559 z");
var gym = paper.path("M 649.042,118.306 631.356,121.326 629.096,108.077 606.631,111.913 605.041,102.605 547.34,112.458 551.19,135.015 548.429,135.487 540.914,136.771 537.715,137.316 540.338,152.688 543.537,152.142 544.654,158.681 541.456,159.227 549.459,206.092 548.493,206.258 547.088,206.497 547.491,208.867 548.896,208.627 549.589,212.683 553.197,212.066 553.504,213.863 556.034,213.432 555.727,211.635 555.56,210.661 661.717,192.533 649.042,118.306 z");


gym.attr({stroke: "none",
            fill:   "#f00",
            "fill-opacity": 0});


//This was just me testing to see hover changes
gym.hover(function () {
    gym.attr({"stroke": "#000"});
},
  function () {
gym.attr({"stroke": "none"});
  });

}
```

I am not sure where to go from here to make the image appear upon hover. Like I said earlier, I am very new to javascript and I appreciate any help that you guys can give me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a model `buildingModel`  in which I store all needed values like image src and temporary image which is created on hover. There is also an array which holds all elements added to paper, for easy access. Feel free to try it.

```
 window.onload = function () {
            var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 718, 454);
            var buildingModel = function (name, raphaelEl, image) {
                var self = this;
                self.Name = name;
                self.Render = raphaelEl
                self.ImageSrc = image;
                self.ImageRender = null;
                self.Render.ParentModel = self;
            };
            var onObjectHoverIn = function () {
                this.ImageRender = paper.image(this.ImageSrc, this.Render.getBBox().x + 100, this.Render.getBBox().y +100, 100, 100);
            };
            var onObjectHoverOut = function () {
                if (this.ImageRender) {
                    this.ImageRender.remove();
                }
            };
            var objects = new Array();

            var building_left = new buildingModel('building left', paper.path("M102.262,272.369L86.617,170.243h-0.001l-1.628-10.632l-0.361-2.355l-0.772-5.045,c3.807-1.873,16.113-3.42,19.919-5.295c16.499-8.117,24.5-16.563,40.998-24.682l5.64,38.233l-44.377,6.801l15.644,102.126,L102.262,272.369L102.262,272.369z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            var building_right = new buildingModel('building_right', paper.path("M 179.229,294.203 255.138,224.116 255.139,224.116 261.668,218.086 264.791,215.203 268.54,211.74 224.758,164.323 211.355,176.695 241.813,209.682 165.905,279.771 179.229,294.203 z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            var building_middle = new buildingModel('building_middle', paper.path("M 121.679,269.394 165.432,284.533 198.59,188.698 154.837,173.561 121.679,269.394 z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            var auditorium = new buildingModel('auditorium', paper.path("M 308.953,287.341 324.306,272.827 434.898,253.264 442.893,259.055 435.941,268.646 457.102,388.746 348.424,407.501 341.092,366.764 312.423,372.086 297.54,289.234 308.953,287.341 z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            var building_hall = new buildingModel('building_hall', paper.path("M 353.574,219.885 345.305,171.459 428.613,157.234 436.881,205.659 353.574,219.885 z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            var office = new buildingModel('office', paper.path("M 476.971,200.559 436.881,172.165 487.543,100.641 527.631,129.036 476.971,200.559 z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            var gym = new buildingModel('gym', paper.path("M 649.042,118.306 631.356,121.326 629.096,108.077 606.631,111.913 605.041,102.605 547.34,112.458 551.19,135.015 548.429,135.487 540.914,136.771 537.715,137.316 540.338,152.688 543.537,152.142 544.654,158.681 541.456,159.227 549.459,206.092 548.493,206.258 547.088,206.497 547.491,208.867 548.896,208.627 549.589,212.683 553.197,212.066 553.504,213.863 556.034,213.432 555.727,211.635 555.56,210.661 661.717,192.533 649.042,118.306 z"), 'http://www.julian-charriere.net/sites/default/files/styles/project_image/public/some_pigeons_are_more_equal_than_other_Charri%C3%A8re_Bismarck3.jpg');
            objects.push(building_left);
            objects.push(building_right);
            objects.push(building_middle);
            objects.push(auditorium);
            objects.push(building_hall);
            objects.push(office);
            objects.push(gym);

            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                var objMod = objects[i];
                objMod.Render.attr({
                    stroke: "none",
                    fill: "#f00",
                    "fill-opacity": 1
                });
                objMod.Render.hover(onObjectHoverIn,onObjectHoverOut,objMod,objMod);
            }



        }
```

If it helps please mark it as an answer or upvote it by one. Thanks!